# How to make sure application isn't accessing private data in Windows?

Tags: windows, security

I have been told to install a client server application, and the problem is that I am using Windows machine.

Any application can easily access any data in Windows machine. How can I make sure that application is working wisely?

Are there some raw ways to tell like watch packets that app is sending and receiving.

Comment: these 2 label conflicts :)

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't
2. You can try with running it with another (unprivileged) user, which is rather difficult, if you need other applications too.

With [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) you can explore what resources process is using, including open files.

With [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) you can start applications with another user's permissions.

Both are from Microsoft's sysinternals package.

As noted in comments, [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is good (and free) network sniffer for monitoring what application is sending to internet, or whether it's downloading some additional payload over network.

Also, it might be good idea to run that application inside virtual machine. That way your normal installation isn't messed up, if it's doing something malicious.

Comment: 2 is somewhat illogical. but there must be some way.

Comment: umm, what do you mean by illogical? When you are running it with another user, it can't access your files (without exploiting windows bug, that is.)

Comment: I agree with olli here, but I want to add that wireshark might be a good choice if you want to analyze what is being sent over the network to the server.

Comment: @Kyle @Olli I meant, suppose I try it with user X then it would be accessing X's private file. I want to make sure.

Comment: trying with process explorer

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I understood you want to protect your files, not check that software in general. Process Explorer and Wireshark are good tools for easily exploring what that software is doing.

Comment: I tried process explorer, it doesn't show my which file app is accessing, also under the cover app can also hook to kernal to get my keystroke and some screen capture and other sensitive stuff.